# Conditional Form Validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have an HTML form with 3 groups of questions which users can answer either yes or no to as follows:

A1
A2
A3
A4
A5

OR

B1
B2
B3

OR

C1
C2
C3
C4
C5
C6

Users can choose to answer either all the "A" questions, all the "B" questions or all the "C" questions but they cannot answer more than one group. Also for whichever group they choose to answer they must answer all questions in the same group (i.e. all the "A" or all the "B" or all the "C" questions - they can't leave a question unanswered).

Here's the HTML for the form:

```
    <form method="post" action="process.php" id='editRecord'>

              <table border="1" class="record">
              <tr>
              <td width="88%" valign="top" class="field_name_left">A1</td>
              <td width="12%" valign="top" class="field_data">         
                            <input type="radio" name="CriteriaA1" value="Yes">Yes<input type="radio" name="CriteriaA1" value="No">No</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td width="88%" valign="top" class="field_name_left">A2</td>
              <td valign="top" class="field_data">
                            <input type="radio" name="CriteriaA2" value="Yes">Yes<input type="radio" name="CriteriaA2" value="No">No</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td width="88%" valign="top" class="field_name_left">A3</td>
              <td valign="top" class="field_data">                       <input type="radio" name="CriteriaA3" value="Yes">Yes<input type="radio" name="CriteriaA3" value="No">No</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td width="88%" valign="top" class="field_name_left">A4</td>
              <td valign="top" class="field_data">
                           <input type="radio" name="CriteriaA4" value="Yes">Yes<input type="radio" name="CriteriaA4" value="No">No</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td width="88%" valign="top" class="field_name_left">A5</td>
              <td valign="top" class="field_data">
                           <input type="radio" name="CriteriaA5" value="Yes">Yes<input type="radio" name="CriteriaA5" value="No">No</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="field_name_left" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="field_name_left" colspan="2"><strong>OR</strong></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="field_name_left" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="field_name_left">B1</td>
                <td valign="top" class="field_data">
                             <input type="radio" name="CriteriaB1" value="Yes">Yes<input type="radio" name="CriteriaB1" value="No">No</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="field_name_left">B2</td>
                <td valign="top" class="field_data">
                             <input type="radio" name="CriteriaB2" value="Yes">Yes<input type="radio" name="CriteriaB2" value="No">No</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="field_name_left">B3</td>
                <td valign="top" class="field_data">
                             <input type="radio" name="CriteriaB3" value="Yes">Yes<input type="radio" name="CriteriaB3" value="No">No</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="field_name_left" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="field_name_left" colspan="2"><strong>OR</strong></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="field_name_left" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td width="88%" valign="top" class="field_name_left">C1</td>
              <td width="12%" valign="top" class="field_data">         
                            <input type="radio" name="CriteriaC1" value="Yes">Yes<input type="radio" name="CriteriaC1" value="No">No</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td width="88%" valign="top" class="field_name_left">C2</td>
              <td valign="top" class="field_data">
                            <input type="radio" name="CriteriaC2" value="Yes">Yes<input type="radio" name="CriteriaC2" value="No">No</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td width="88%" valign="top" class="field_name_left">C3</td>
              <td valign="top" class="field_data">
                           <input type="radio" name="CriteriaC3" value="Yes">Yes<input type="radio" name="CriteriaC3" value="No">No</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td width="88%" valign="top" class="field_name_left">C4</td>
              <td valign="top" class="field_data">
                           <input type="radio" name="CriteriaC4" value="Yes">Yes<input type="radio" name="CriteriaC4" value="No">No</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td width="88%" valign="top" class="field_name_left">C5</td>
              <td valign="top" class="field_data">
                           <input type="radio" name="CriteriaC5" value="Yes">Yes<input type="radio" name="CriteriaC5" value="No">No</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td width="88%" valign="top" class="field_name_left">C6</td>
              <td valign="top" class="field_data">
                           <input type="radio" name="CriteriaC6" value="Yes">Yes<input type="radio" name="CriteriaC6" value="No">No</td>
              </tr>

              <tr class="submit_btn">
                <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
              <tr class="submit_btn">
                <td colspan="3">
                    <div id="buttons" >
                        <input type="submit" name="-edit" value="Continue">
                        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">  
                    </div>              
                    <div id="error"></div>            </td>
             </tr>
        </table>
    </form>​
```

I've also setup a jsFiddle at:

http://jsfiddle.net/fmdataweb/pEETU/2/

I would like to add some client side validation to check when the user clicks the Continue button that they have indeed answered all questions in one group and have not answered any questions from another group.

I previously had this validating when the form only had A or B options - the form now has the C options and I need to update the Javascript but everything I've tried so far has failed.

Here's the Javascript that works for the original A and B options:

```
    $(function() {

        $("#editRecord").submit(function(){

        // is anything checked?
        if(!checkEmpty()){
            $("#error").html("Please check something before submitting");
            //alert("nothing Checked");
            return false;
        }
        // Only A _OR_ B
        if(isAorB()){
            $("#error").html("Please complete A or B, not both");
            //alert("please complete A or B, not both");
            return false;
        };
        // all A's or all B's
        if(allAorBChecked()){
            $("#error").html("It appears you have not completed all questions");
            //alert("missing data");
            return false;
        };
        if(haveNo()){
            // we're going on, but sending "type = C"
        }
        //alert("all OK");
            return true;
        });
    });


function checkEmpty(){
    var OK = false;
    $(":radio").each(function(){
        if (this.checked){
            OK = true;
        }
    });
    return OK;
}
 function isAorB(){
    var OK = false;
    var Achecked = false;
    var Bchecked = false;
    $(":radio").each(function(){
        var theChar=this.name.charAt(8);
        // if we have an A checked remember it
         if(theChar == "A" && this.checked && !Achecked){
            Achecked = true;    
        }
        if(Achecked && theChar == "B" && !Bchecked){
            if(this.checked){
                Bchecked = true;
            }
        }
        if (Achecked && Bchecked){
            OK = true;
        }
    });
    return OK;
} 
function allAorBChecked(){
    var notOK = false;
    var Achecked = false;
    $(":radio").each(function(){
        // skip through to see if we're doing A's or B's
    var theChar=this.name.charAt(8);
        // check the A's
     if(theChar == "A" && this.checked && !Achecked){
            Achecked = true;    
        }

    });
    if(Achecked){
        // set the input to A
        $("#type").val("A");
        // check _all_ a's are checked
        var thisName;
        var thisChecked = false;

        $(":radio").each(function(){
            var theChar=this.name.charAt(8);
            var checked = this.checked;
            if (theChar == "A"){
            if (this.name == thisName && !thisChecked){
                // Yes wasn't checked - is No?
                if(!checked){
                    notOK = true;
                }
            }
            thisChecked = checked;
            thisName = this.name;
        }
    });
    }else{
        // set the input to B
        $("#type").val("B");            
        // check _all_ b's are checked
            var thisName;
            var thisChecked = false;
            $(":radio").each(function(){
                var theChar=this.name.charAt(8);
                var checked = this.checked;
                if (theChar == "B"){
                if (this.name == thisName && !thisChecked){
                    // A wasn't checked - is B?
                    if(!checked){
                        notOK = true;
                    }
                }
                thisChecked = checked;
                thisName = this.name;
            }
        });
    }
    return notOK;
}    
function haveNo(){
    var thisName;
    var notOK = false;
        $(":radio").each(function(){
            var checked = this.checked;
            if (this.name == thisName){
                //Is this checked 
                if(checked){
                    notOK = true;
                    $("#type").val("C");            
                }

        }
        thisName = this.name;
    });

    return notOK;
}
```

​

Comment: It can be done with jquery easily, and the validate plugin is not a must. I would suggest you atleast attempt the solution, and then maybe someone will help clear the doubts.
Don't expect people to write entire code for you.

Comment: You probably shouldn't put your form in a table like that. Your form is not filled with tabular data, calling it one is poor semantics.

Comment: Im with Shahil, write something by your own and then ask. Try it at least... I would use jQuery, is not so complicate.

Comment: Sorry I've now included the Javascript that was working before I added the C options to the form. I've been trying to extend this script to handle the C options with the same rules as for A or B but I just keep breaking the validation, and after about 5 hours I could really do with some help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the most excellent jQuery Validation Plugin http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation you can use "depends" to make fields only required when other criteria are met.

To make sure that only one set of fields is filled out, you could just make the others invisible (and empty any values programmatically) once clicked. The problem I see is when someone starts clicking on radio buttons and then decides they want to fill out the b data...how are they going to remove all their radio buttons in A?